# Migrate data from MySQL to eXist in Orbeon Forms

Tags: mysql, orbeon, exist-db

We need migrate data from MySQL to eXist database because of bad performance of MySQL persistence layer in Orbeon Forms. How can we do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, Orbeon Forms doesn't come with a "migration tool" that would enable you to move data between databases. You could program this in whatever language you are the most familiar with, accessing [Orbeon's persistence API](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api), but if you have 50 forms, and this is a one-time operation, however boring that might sound, it might be faster to just do 50 copy-pastes.

Comment: thank you for your help. Could you advice me how can I use copy-paste approach?

Comment: @Bolatik You can access the source of each form in the sidebar, with *Edit Source*. Copy the source, paste it into a file, move it to the other machine, and there open the file, create a new form with whatever app/form name, go to edit source, and paste the source. Repeat for every form.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Form Builder to build your forms, another trick you can use is to switch between persistence providers. Since Orbeon Forms supports dynamic resource reloading, you don't need to restart to switch providers.

1. Configure your original provider (properties-local.xml)
2. Open the form in Form Builder
3. Configure your new provider
4. In Form Builder, click Save

I found this technique useful, though I only needed to do it for one form definition.

See http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/oracle-and-mysql-persistence-layers for docs on persistence providers.